# How do I emit data over socket io every time the database is updated?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am building a system where I have a standalone administrative dashboard with a client interface. The front end is built on angularjs, and I'm using a boilerplate Node.js/Express server on the backend, which I have connected to a MySql database.

Every time a client submits new information from the client interface, it is submitted to the server, routed by the router to a controller, which passes the data to a model and uploads it to the database.

What I would like to do is every time the controller is called that handles the request, after the request has completed, I want to emit the new data over socket.io to the administrative dashboard.

My challenge is I have no idea how to access the socket from within the controller??? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it's tricky. Like Express, Socket.io a request handling library of its own. They both work separately and independently, so there's no easy way to "switch" from Express to Socket.

However if you can identify a client uniquely, you can store its `socket.id` somewhere and then you can use the `io` from your Express controller to emit to that client's socket.

You can do `io.to(socket.id).emit` which is same as `socket.emit`, so as long as you have `socket.id` you can emit to it using `io` which is globally available.

I use [Passport](http://passportjs.org) authentication in most apps so I find that using `req.user` is a great way to uniquely identify a client. It can even be a behind-the-scenes "pseudo" authentication by generating random userid/pass for each client.

Then there's this [passport.socketio](https://github.com/jfromaniello/passport.socketio) module to Access passport.js user information from a socket.io connection. [Here's an article from the author that goes into the details of it all](https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/15/auth-with-socket-io/).

Using them together you can use the `user` object to store and access `socket.id` and use it to communicate to the client via socket.io

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    var user = socket.request.user; // from socketio.passport

    // store the socket.id inside the user so it can be retrieved from Express
    user.socketid = socket.id;
});
```

```
app.post('/form', function(req, res, next){
    var user = req.user;           // from Passport
    var socketid = user.socket.id  // from socket above

    var data = req.body;
    doStuff(data);

    io.to(socketid).emit('done');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! This looks pretty intense, so I'm going to dive into this today and see what I can do. Couple questions for you. For both of these parts - do they take place in the main app.js file? or is "app.post" in the router? How is "user.socketid" getting passed to the app.post?

Comment: `req.user` ≈ `socket.request.user`, so in a way that (`user`) is your "bridge" between Express and Socket. When you'll have configured Passport and socketio.passport, it'll all make much more sense.